# Where can I find a whole bunch of complicated PGN files?

Tags: pgn

I'm interested to test that the atom syntax highlighter for pgn files -- https://atom.io/packages/language-pgn -- can handle the full range of possible files.  Is there a suite of difficult test files somewhere?

Also related might be this question:

[What are all of the possible tags for PGN?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/what-are-all-of-the-possible-tags-for-pgn)

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18046/what-are-the-biggest-free-chess-databases-is-it-legal-to-download-games-from-th

Answer (score 2):

As an author of some PGN-processing software, I would also be interested in having access to a general test suite but I am not aware of any, unfortunately, and all I can offer is some advice based on experience.

I would be wary of throwing a large database of games at an application in order to test it before you have developed reasonable confidence with its fundamentals. In the early stages, at least, I find it most effective to create a lot of small examples, each of which tests an individual feature. That way, errors are relatively easy to spot because they don't get lost in a mass of output. Once I have got rid of the basic errors I would then look at combining a small number of both related and unrelated features in individual tests to make sure that there is no unexpected interference between the associated functionality. Only late on would I switch to large datasets to make sure there are no issues with scaling up.

I also highly recommend re-running all the existing tests each time a new feature is added. I have been amazed how often I have unexpectedly broken something seemingly unrelated as the code has developed.

Apologies if these principles are already well known to you!

Answer (score -1):

http://www.chessgames.com might be a good place.

Another one is http://www.top-5000.nl/pgn.htm